# How to deal with characters such as "" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I'd like to convert "HELLO" to "HELLO", removing all the special characters that cause problems when inserted into the database. They do not seem to be part of UTF8.

I'm trying to figure out [Iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html), but I'm kind of stuck here:

```
str = "A string with " to "A string with "
some_format = "I have no clue what format this is"
Iconv.conv(some_format, 'UTF-8//IGNORE', str)
```

Doing this:

```
Iconv.conv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', str)
```

... returns ...

```
\376\377\000H\000E\000L\000L\000O?G?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?`?????\342
```

I don't want to convert to something else than UTF8 because I have to deal with arabic characters, chinese, japanese, korean...

Any help/pointers would be appreciated. I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 but I should migrate to 1.9.3 very shortly. A solution that works in both situation is best, but one for only 1.9.3 is fine too.

Comment: Where are these "characters" coming from? If they're "not part of utf-8" (which I'm not sure even makes sense), what encoding are they in when you get them?

Comment: @Wooble: They come from user inputs. I'm not sure what they are supposed to be. Since there is a UTF-16, it can make sense http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: but UTF-8 and UTF-16 are just encodings of the unicode character set. If a glyph exists in unicode, it can be represented in either encoding. I'm guessing what you really have is not characters, but bytes in some unknown encoding. You must ensure that when taking input from a user you know what encoding they're sending it in.

Comment: @Wooble Oh ok I see your point. But how can I know the encoding? I'm actually calling an API that is returning this, so I don't have a lot of control of how the data is entered.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to remove characters not present in a specific encoding (when converting a string to another encoding)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "⚒og"
p a => ⚒og
p a.encode('iso-8859-1', :undef => :replace, :replace => '') => og
```

However your problem might be different. Because It is very unlikely that those problematic characters are not part of utf-8. 
Possible problems:

1. Maybe it is simply that the font you use don't know how to display those characters. Very few fonts have complete utf-8 character coverage.
   I don't know how you try to display those strings but make sure you use a font with a good character coverage. Like DejaVu for example, http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page
2. Are you sure your database is correctly configured to use utf-8?
3. Also be careful, because your string might be perfectly fine, but not displayed in your terminal or database application because of incomplete utf-8 support (happened to me before). So sometimes it gets tricky to debug when your debugging display is bugged... (does it make sense?)